# How can I use addAttributeToFilter to search in Magento for a multi-select value in db?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, addattribute

I have values in database in array and I want to search values also from an array.

For example :

I have an array `('13,14')` and in database I have values like `(13,14)` or `(13)` or `(14)` or `(15)`. So when I search `('13,14')` results should appear with values containing at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a collection, as `addAttributeToFilter()` is a collection method. Here's how your filter your collection with a set of possibilities, for a given attribute :

```
$myCollection->addAttributeToFilter('id', array('in' => array('13','14')));
```

`'id'` being the name of your attribute. You can also use the operator `nin` instead of `in`, to specify a set of values you don't want your attribute value to be in. Check the other operators here : https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/